# Keeping a copy of a file in a same directory

Tags: linux

I am working on linux scripts , Assume that the directory is consisting of these following  scripts .

```
ls *.sh

test.sh 
MyScripts.sh
```

My question is , before making any modifications to test.sh script , i want to keep a backup copy of it , so that if anything messes up , i will be not screwed up .
please tell me how can i keep a copy of test.sh in the same directory ?? before making any modifications to the actual file test.sh .

Thank you very much .

Comment: Have you considered using proper version control system?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Consider using [revision control](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Version_control), such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).

You can make a copy before your work too:

```
cp test.sh test.sh.orig
```

Comment: Works only in bash. I think clarity > smartness here (obviously, the OP is not a commandline wizard, or he wouldn't have asked the question in the first place)

Comment: Good point. I just get used to the shortcuts I use and didn't really think about it. I changed my `cp` command.

Answer (score 6):

The usual approach is to

```
 cp test.sh test.sh~
```

(or `test.sh.bck` or whatever naming convention). In fact, any decent editor should have an option to do this automatically for you. Vim does it by default (saves a backup name filename~ on modification)

#### *May I heartily suggest a version control solution for this purpose instead*?

Good 'starter' options include:

- bazaar
- mercurial

I personally vouch for `git`.

<sub>I took care to name (D)VCS methods that have ample interoperability options so as to prevent data lockin.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```
cp test.sh test.sh.`date +"%m_%d_%Y"`
```

Will make a timestamped backup named `test.sh.10_10_2011`